# How to change the String to Double in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I change the String to Double? but I got this error. Please help me solve the problem. Thank you.

**product.dart file** (These was String before)

```
class Product {
  double ogPrice;
  double price;
```

**productdetails.dart. Here's a file that has an error.**

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
  children: <Widget>[
    Text(
      '${Config().currency}${(widget.product.price)}',
      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
        color: Colors.green.shade700,
        fontSize: 16.0,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
        letterSpacing: 0.3,
      ),
    ),
    SizedBox(
      width: 5.0,
    ),
    Text(
      '${Config().currency}${widget.product.ogPrice}',
      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
        color: Colors.black54,
        decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
        fontSize: 15.0,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
        letterSpacing: 0.3,
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

**And I got this error**

lib/widgets/product_detail.dart:43:43: Error: The argument type 'double' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'. (int.parse(widget.product.price) /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write something like:

```
widget.product.ogPrice.toString()
```

or If you want to give digits after decimal point:

```
widget.product.ogPrice.toStringAsFixed(2)
```

Hope it will help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because the `Text` widget always expects `String`, but what you are giving is `double`.  In order for it to work, you are supposed to convert value to string via `.toString()` method.

Answer (score -1):

You have declared price of type **double**. And you are trying to display a double value in a widget that accepts only **string** type. So you need to **typecast** double to string using **toString()**.

```
widget.product.price.toString()
widget.product.ogPrice.toString()
```